# Prevent click after a certain child when event handler is attached to parent

Tags: javascript

I have the following structure:

```
<ul id="list-items">
    <li class="item" data-id="123" data-title="Some Title">
        <div class="block">
            <img src="#"/>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <p>Some excerpt</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

- There are more than 1 `<li>` item
- All `data-` attributes are on the `<li>` elements

Using jQuery, I would usually make use of event delegation instead of attaching event handlers on every `<li>` item:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.item', function() {
    var id    = $( this ).data( 'id' );
    var title = $( this ).data( 'title' );
});
```

However, I am not able to replicate this using Pure JavaScript.
I want to be able to click on an `<li>` item without clicking any of its child elements.

I am also not at the liberty of using [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) since we have to provide support for IE11. Is there a simpler way to implement it?

**EDIT:**
I am avoiding attaching event listeners to each `<li>` item as it won't work for dynamically created `<li>` elements, and also for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the `li`'s content from getting any mouse event by setting a `pointer-events: none` to it.

```html
<li class="item" data-id="123" data-title="Some Title">
    <div class="block" style="pointer-events: none">
        <img src="#"/>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <p>Some excerpt</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

You can guarantee now that the `event.target` will always be the `li`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to attach event handler on all the items directly. you can attach only one event handler on the parent like this

```
var element = document.querySelector("#vanilla-parent")
element.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.composedPath().forEach(function(elm){
    if (elm.tagName === 'LI') {
      // do something
    }
  });
});

$("#jquery-parent").on("click", "li", function(event){
   // do something
});
```

Pen demonstrating the same: https://codepen.io/kireeti-tiki/pen/EzPpqZ?editors=1010

I used composedPath on the event object to get to li, I wouldn't recommend this as this is a bit of hacky way to get to the solution. Also, it is not supported on IE and Edge. So stay away from that solution if you need support for those browsers. More on that subject here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

If using jQuery is not a problem, Then I would recommend that approach.

Comment: Answer by Ryan Wilson looks more accurate.

Comment: @SiddharthThevaril is right, this seems like an elegant solution but the tag returned is that of the tags inside the `li`

Comment: @SiddharthThevaril, Rager. Yes the code previously shared wasn't working. Thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected the code and provided a link to the pen demonstrating the same.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like get all li and attach an eventlistener do?

```
<script>

    var li_list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for(var i = 0; i < li_list.length; i++) {
        (function(index) {
            li_list[index].addEventListener("click", function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('clicked')
            })
        })(i);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: as I said in the question, I'm avoiding attaching event handlers to every `<li>` item for 2 reasons, first is that they are refreshed by AJAX response, another is due to performance reasons.

Comment: Only if you use document.addEventListener and listen to the click then...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using [**Element.closest()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), for which there is a polyfill.

```js
function attachClickHandler() {
  const list = document.querySelector('.list');
  list.addEventListener('click', (item) => {
    // console.log('Item:', item);
    const closest = item.target.closest('li');
    console.log('Closest li:', closest);
    console.log('Data on closest li:', closest.tagName, closest.dataset && closest.dataset.id || 'no data');
    
    // alternative
    console.log(' === alt ===');
    let elem = item.target;    
    while (elem.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'li') {
      elem = elem.parentNode;      
      if (elem.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'ul') {
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log('Manual version:', elem.tagName, elem.dataset && elem.dataset.id || 'no data');
  });
  console.log('Listening.');
}

attachClickHandler();
```

```html
<h1>My list</h1>
<ul class="list">
  <li data-id="1">Item 1</li>
  <li data-id="2"><button>Item 2</button></li>
  <li>Empty item</li>
</ul>
```

*Edit*: This won't work on IE as stackoverflow likely doesn't load the polyfill. But if you test it standalone (should be 3 seconds work) you can verify if it's good enough for you.